# ao_play(), whats the playing time for X number of bytes of audio block?

Tags: linux, audio

Thanks in advance.

I am trying to play audio after from a file. For this I wanted to know the exact time consumption of ao_play() for X number of bytes input.

Please let me know your answer

Comment: Are you asking about the exact parameters that you need to feed into libao's ao_play() function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading [the prototype for the ao_play function](http://www.xiph.org/ao/doc/ao_play.html):

```
int ao_play(ao_device *device, char *output_samples, uint_32 num_bytes);
```

You are going to feed `output_samples` with a pointer to your audio buffer. `num_bytes` is the length of the output_samples buffer in bytes.

The math for computing `num_bytes` can be tricky. Basically:

```
(number of samples) * (bytes per sample)
```

If you have 1000 samples and each sample is 16 bits wide (i.e., 2 bytes per sample), `num_bytes` will be 2000.

Comment: I still got doubt

int ao_play(ao_device *device, char *output_samples, 5376);

format is 16bit Sampling is at 44100Hz...

What will be the play time of it...?

Answer (score 0):

miliseconds = (1000*buffer-len) / (samples * channels * (bits/8))